# Parsing XML in Javascfipt

Tags: javascript, xml, arrays, parsing, appcelerator

Ok I am trying to parse an XML from a get request in Javascript. 
This is how the XML looks like

```
<markers>
<marker>
<name>
<![CDATA[ Pan Africa Market ]]>
</name>
<address>
<![CDATA[ 1521 1st Ave, Seattle, WA ]]>
</address>
<lat>47.608940</lat>
<lng>-122.340141</lng>
<price>150</price>
<type>restaurant</type>
</marker>
</markers>
```

I am trying to push the marker into an array so I can access it later (I am building a google maps marker with it)

In the result var I save the response from the get request (This is working perfect I know it cause I can alert the "params.length")

```
var result = this.responseText;

var xml = Ti.XML.parseString(result);
var items = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

var name = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("name");
var value = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("address");

var data = [];

for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
         alert(items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).text);



}
```

I can alert the items prices (1 by 1 of course), but the question is how can I save that so I can access it later.
I red that I have to push it into the data variable in the for loop but I just dont know how.

Thanks in advance.
PD Im using it in Appcelerator. (I think this is not very important)

Comment: I have a question and a couple of comments: What's TI (since you tagged your post as AppCelerator, I am assuming it has something to do with that)? When you use 'getElementsByTagName', you get an array not a single value. There may be just one tag with the name you specified but it's going to be in an array (actually in a list of nodes). You 'data' array will either have to be 2D or contain objects since you want to save both ‘name’ and ‘value’ on the same index (I assume).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

var data = [];

for (var i=0;i<markers.length;i++) {
    console.log(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0]);
    data.push({
        name: markers[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].textContent,
        address: markers[i].getElementsByTagName("address")[0].textContent 
    })
}
// data is now [{name: "...", address: "..." }]
```

See working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/XZnXn/

For more on navigating a DOM structure in Javascript, you might want to look at the [MDN DOM Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference).

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but let me get this straight... Now the variable data has in it an array, so I could access the elements from the array like this: data.markers1.name ??  Am I correct?

Comment: Arrays are accessed with `[]`, so it would be `data[0].name`, etc.